# Split comma separated and quoted string into an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, shell

I need to split a comma separated, but quoted list of strings into an indexed bash array in a script.

I know there are a lot of posts on the web in general and also on SO that show how to create an indexed array from a given line / string, but I could not find any example that does the array elements the way I need.  I apologise, if I have missed any obvious examples from SO itself.

I am reading a file that I receive from someone, and cannot change it.

The file is formatted like this

```
"Grant ACL","grantacls.sh"
"Revoke ACL","revokeacls.sh"
"Get ACls for Topic","topicacls.sh"
"Get Topics for User with ACLs","useracls.sh"
```

I need to create an array for each line above where the separator is comma - and each of the quoted string will be an array element.  I have tried various options.  The latest attempt was using a construct like this - copied from some example on the web

```
  parseScriptMapLine=${scriptName[$IN_OPTION]}
  mapfile -td ',' script1 < <(echo -n "${parseScriptMapLine//, /,}")
  declare -p script1
  echo "script1 $script1"
```

where script name is an associative array created from the original file, whose format is with 1, 2, etc. as the key and the other part after '=' sign as value.

The above snippet prints
`script1`

And the value part I need to split into an indexed array, so that I can pass the second element as a parameter.  When creating indexed array from the value string, if I have to lose the quotes, that is fine or if it creates the elements with the quotes, that is fine too.

```
1="Grant ACL","grantacls.sh"
2="Revoke ACL","revokeacls.sh"
3="Get ACls for Topic","topicacls.sh"
4="Get Topics for User with ACLs","useracls.sh"
```

I have looked at a lot of examples, but haven't been able to get this particular requirement working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With apologies, I could not understand what you wanted - this sounds like an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you clarify?

Maybe this?

```
$: while IFS=',"' read -r _ a _ _ d _ && [[ -n "$d" ]]; do echo "a=[$a] d=[$d]"; done < file
a=[Grant ACL] d=[grantacls.sh]
a=[Revoke ACL] d=[revokeacls.sh]
a=[Get ACls for Topic] d=[topicacls.sh]
a=[Get Topics for User with ACLs] d=[useracls.sh]
```

That will let you do whatever you wanted with the fields, which I named `a` and `d`.

If you just want to load the lines of the file into an array -

```
$: mapfile -t script1 < file
$: for i in "${!script1[@]}"; do echo "$i=${script1[i]}"; done
0="Grant ACL","grantacls.sh"
1="Revoke ACL","revokeacls.sh"
2="Get ACls for Topic","topicacls.sh"
3="Get Topics for User with ACLs","useracls.sh"
```

If you want a two-dimensional array, then sorry, you're going to have to use something besides `bash`. or get more creative.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to add some background to make the problem clear but that made it more unclear.

So, in short from line `"Grant ACL","grantacls.sh"`, I wanted to create an indexed array that will have elements `array[0]="Grant ACL"` and `array[1]="grantacls.sh"`.  And then I could do something to get the string without the quotes.  

Form the examples above, even if it is not an array,  I think I can work with the first part in your example.

Comment: in a loop, if you don't intend to keep the values over following iterations, then named variables is probably better. If you are keeping them, then it's possible to make a kludgy mockup of a multidimensional array in bash using Associative arrays, though at that point I would probably just recommend using another language like perl or even awk. If you need me to demonstrate, let me know, but I advise the simple approach.  If that works for you, please accept the response. :)